# How to start writing a firewall for linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, firewall

I want to develope a firewall for Linux. I prefer C/C++ language.

Is there any simple sample code for writing a firewall?

Which libraries should I use?

Update: There are some firewalls for Linux, but I want develope a simple firewall for learning.

Comment: It is already implemented in the kernel with *iptables*; you just need to configure and tune them.

Comment: I want develope a simple firewall for some learning reasons.

Comment: As @BasileStarynkevitch said, it's already there, but take a look at http://www.netfilter.org/ if you want to learn more, also heed the warnings on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391/how-would-i-get-started-writing-my-own-firewall

Comment: It's not clear at all what you want to do.  What exactly is that "firewall" supposed to do?  Just set up netfilter rules?  Deep packet inspection?  What protocols?  And why do you want to write one yourself, instead of using one of the oodles already out there?

Comment: @Sven, agreed, but *firewall* is not a very precise term.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: That's exactly my point.

Comment: Who on earth would close such a reasonable question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start by using the Netfilters API (http://www.netfilter.org/). I think it is a good starting point for packet filtering. I've worked a lot with this API in kernel space. I'm not sure if there is a library for user land, but I must tell you that it's pretty easy to develop something with netfilters in the kernel.

As an example, iptables use the netfilters API.